# highcharts adding data use textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/qp32j9mt/4/ this my highchart full code.. when i put some value in textbox add every value in highcharts data(like voting concept)..

```
$(function () {

  $('#btn').click(function(){

     var val1 = parseFloat($('input[id=m]').val());
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            //allowDecimals: false,
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                }
            }
        },
```

please help me

Comment: i want add every values..like voting concept..

Comment: Where u want to store ????  and ur question is not proper.. i can't help u wid this..

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained your question well.  What does "like voting concept" mean?

I'm going to take a guess and assume you want to add a new point on each "add data" button click.

First, draw a plot with no data.  Then:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
    var val1 = parseFloat($('input[id=m]').val());
    chart.series[0].addPoint(val1);                  
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qp32j9mt/5/).